# Docker Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, puppeteer

I try to install and create user for `Puppeteer` in my docker container. But I got an `ERROR` about user permission for `mkdir`.
Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY backend/package.json backend/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY backend/src/ ./src
COPY backend/.env ./
COPY backend/.babelrc ./
RUN mkdir -p build/src
RUN npm run build

FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache \
      chromium \
      nss \
      freetype \
      harfbuzz \
      ca-certificates \
      ttf-freefont

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
    PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

RUN npm install puppeteer@10.0.0

RUN addgroup -S pptruser && adduser -S -g pptruser pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads /app \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app

# RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser  \
#     && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads /app \
#     && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
#     && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app

USER pptruser
# USER root

COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/package-lock.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/.env ./
COPY --from=builder /app/build ./build
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["node", "build/src/index.js"]
```

I used addgroup and adduser to create a user. I followed this document `https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker`.
And I got an error:

```
backend    | Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/app/build/src/services/csv'
backend    |     at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1334:3)
backend    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/src/services/download.js:36:16)
backend    |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
backend    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
backend    |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
backend    |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
backend    |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
backend    |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
backend    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/src/services/index.js:11:17)
backend    |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14) {
backend    |   errno: -13,
backend    |   syscall: 'mkdir',
backend    |   code: 'EACCES',
backend    |   path: '/app/build/src/services/csv'
backend    | }
```

My function I got that `Error`:

```
const csvFolder = path.join(__dirname, "csv");
if (!fs.existsSync(csvFolder)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(csvFolder);
}
```

But when I user : `USER root`. I don't get this error.
My directory tree:

```
|-src
| |-services
| |-routes
| |-controllers
|-docker
| |-Dockerfile.backend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its due to you are using 2 images for builder, another one for runner.

So while you copy `build` folder from builder to runner, the permission does not keep on both container.

If you use 1 image as the link given, it will run successfully without error as you mentioned above.

`FROM alpine` only.

Comment: I'm newbie with docker and that code is from my leader. He released that. So I think it's ok. Can I ask you a question?
My project need to build before run it. So I use builder and runner. If I must change that dockerfile. Can you give me any solution?
Thank you

Comment: hi @HuỳnhMinhTrí, have you solved this problem? I got same problem because I'm trying to use puppeteer, and need to copy the build folder in stage 2, but got error `EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/app/build/3bc629d5f743a1772f7a775c5f5fb0c1.js'`. Tried using 1 image only but still not working